# Compact operators on an infinite dimensional Banach space cannot be surjective

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, compact-operators

I am reading a book about functional analysis and have a question:

> Let $X$ be a infinite-dimensional Banach-space and $A:X \rightarrow X$ a compact operator. How can one show that $A$ can not be surjective?

Comment: What is your preferred definition of "compact operator"? Proofs might look quite different depending on which definition you use.

Comment: Jonas has given an answer, but you can also remember that in the context of Banach spaces or more generally complete metrizable topological vector spaces, surjective (continuous) linear maps are automatically *open*. Thus you would have $$c B_X\subset A(B_X)$$ where $c$ is a positive real number and $B_X$ is the unit ball in $X$. The left hand side has compact closure iff $X$ is finite dimensional by a theorem of Riesz, while the right hand side has compact closure by definition of $A$ being compact. So $X$ must be finite dimensional for $A$ to be compact and surjective.

Comment: @Olivier: Please add that as an answer.

Comment: @t.b. ok, done.

Comment: What about the case when $A\colon X\rightarrow Y$, when $X\neq Y$ in general?

Comment: Then there can be surjection for sure. Take $Y = \mathbb R$ for example and a non zero functional $f: X\to \mathbb R$. @charlestoncrabb

Answer (score 20):

By popular request ^^ this comment is made into an answer.

Jonas has already given an answer, but here's another one. You can remember that in the context of Banach spaces (or more generally complete metrizable topological vector spaces), surjective (continuous) linear maps are automatically *open*. Thus you would have $$c B_X\subset A(B_X)$$ where $c$ is a positive real number and $B_X$ is the unit ball in $X$. The left hand side has compact closure iff $X$ is finite dimensional by a theorem of Riesz, while the right hand side has compact closure by definition of $A$ being compact. So $X$ must be finite dimensional for $A$ to be compact and surjective.

Comment: Thanks for moving this to the answer section. Since I had them already prepared: links to the [open mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28functional_analysis%29) and [Riesz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma#Converse).

Comment: @t.b. great additions!

Comment: Why $c B_X \subset A (B_X)$? Thank you!

Comment: @r.pomegranate $A(B_X)$ is open by the open mapping theorem, and contains zero, so there is some positive real number $c$ such that $cB_X$ is contained in $A(B_X)$.

Comment: If $A : X \to Y$, where Y is infinite-dimensional, how can we obtain a contradiction? A is open, then $A(B_1(0_X))$ is an open set and bounded, so there is $c > 0$ such that $A(B_1(0_X)) \subset B_c(0_Y)$. But, does $B_c(0_Y)$ contain the unit ball, such that we can obtain the contradiction?

Comment: @r.pomegranate finite rank continuous linear maps are always compact.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $A$ is invertible. Then $I = A^{-1}A$ must also be compact. But $I$ cannot be compact in a infinite-dimensional space.

To prove the last statement note that since $X$ is infinite dimensional, the space contains a sequence of unit vectors $\{x_n\}_n$ in $X$ which does not contain a convergent subsequence (Riesz's lemma). Hence $\{I x_n\} = \{x_n\}$ does not contain a convergent subsequence, hence $I$ cannot be compact.

Comment: But how can you reduce to $A$ invertible? (just saying that you should probably explain this as well)

Comment: and what if $A$ is not invertible?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not fresh enough now to explain why we can reduce to non-invertibility. I'll check it out tomorrow.

Comment: Why if $A$ is invertible, then $I=A^{-1} A$ must also be compact?

Comment: @Chau You can use the first isomorphism theorem, and show that the induced bijection is bounded (and hence its inverse) and also compact, and apply the result of this answer.

Comment: @Toasted_Brain Perhaps one can easily modify the result that for $K$ and $B$ operators on a Hilbert space $H$, $K$ compact and $B$ bounded, both $KB$ and $BK$ are compact.

Answer (score 4):

I would appeal to Banach open mapping theorem. Suppose $A$ is surjective: then, since $X$ is complete it needs be an open mapping. So $A$ maps the unit ball into some precompact open set, which cannot exist in a infinite-dimensional normed space because of Riesz's lemma - the same Jonas mentions. Indeed, a precompact open set $U$ of $X$ would contain a ball of radius $r$. Call $y_n=\frac{r}{2}x_n$, where $x_n$ is the sequence of unit vectors prescribed by the lemma. Then $y_n \in U$ and so it should have a convergent subsequence, which is a contradiction.

**Note** [**EDIT** This example is wrong, see comment by nullUser below.] It is important to assume completeness of $X$. This hypothesis enables us to summon Banach open mapping theorem and without it the claim is *false*. For example, consider the space 
$$c_{00}= \{\mathbf{x}=(x_n)_{n \in \mathbf{N}} \mid x_n=0\ \text{for all sufficiently large}\ n\} $$
equipped with the norm 
$$\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert x_n\rvert^2.$$
This space is not complete and, indeed, the operator $T\colon c_{00} \to c_{00}$ defined by 
$$T(\mathbf{x})=(x_1, \frac{x_2}{2}, \frac{x_3}{3}, \ldots)$$
is compact and surjective.

Comment: How is that operator compact? Take $T(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots,1/n,0,0,0,\ldots)$. The operands are in $c_{00}$ and $\ell^2$ bounded. But their output tends to $(1,1/4,1/9,\ldots,1/n^2,\ldots)$ which is not an element of $c_{00}$, so there can be no convergent subsequence in $c_{00}$.

Comment: @nullUser: I guess that you are right. I had hastily classified that operator as 'compact' because indeed it is a compact operator from $\ell^2$ into $\ell^2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a completion of one of the answers. There it is argued that if $A:X\to Y$ is invertible then $I=A^{-1}A$ is compact, and therefore $X$ must be finite dimensional. The question is what happens if $A$ is *not* invertible.

If $A$ is not invertible, then the preceding argument implies that $X/\ker A\eqsim Y$ is finite dimensional. However, we have $Y=X$ so $X$ must be finite dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

We need the following result, i.e.,

> [Brezis' exercise 6.8](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721688/brezis-exercise-6-8-a-compact-operator-with-closed-range-is-a-finite-rank-oper) Let $E, F$ be Banach spaces and $T:E\to F$ a compact bounded linear operator. We denote by $R(T)$ and $N(T)$ the range and kernel of $T$. Assume that $R(T)$ is closed.
>
> 1. Prove that $T$ is a finite-rank operator.
> 2. Assume, in addition, that $\dim N(T)<\infty$. Prove that $\dim E<\infty$.

Assume the contradiction that $A$ is surjective. Then $R(A)= X$ is closed. Then  by (1), $A$ has finite-rank and thus $\dim R(A) = \dim X < \infty$, which is a contradiction. This completes the proof.