# bounded operator whose image is contained in the image of a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $A,K$ be 2 linear operators from $X$ to $Y$ (Banach spaces). $A$ is bounded and $K$ is compact. If $A(X)\subset K(X)$, is it true that $A$ is alse compact?

I know that if the rank of $K$ is finite, then $A$ must be compact. But I have no idea about the infinite rank case. Any hint would help.

Comment: Yes.  An equivalent formulation of compact operator is that the image under $K$ of closed unit ball in $X$ has compact closure in $Y$.  Since the image of the closed unit ball in $X$ under the operator $A$ is a subset of the image of this ball under $K$, we also get the same set inclusion for their closures.  Since the closure for $K$ is compact, so too is it such for the closure for $A$.

Comment: To have $A(B) \subseteq cK(B)$ for the unit ball $B$ and some constant $c>0$ you need an additional argument, e.g. the closed graph theorem applied to $A: X\to K(X)$ where $K(X)$ is endowed with the quotient norm.

Comment: @Jochen by the quotient norm you mean the graph norm? i.e, $||x|| + ||Kx||$?

Comment: @L.F.Cavenaghi No, the quotient norm on the range of an operator $K$ is $\|y\| =\inf \{\|x\| : K(x)=y\}$.

Comment: @Jochen, how do you apply the open mapping theorem if $A$ is not surjective?

Comment: Where did I say *open mapping theorem*? You can apply the closed graph theorem.

Comment: Sorry @Jochen, I thought maybe the correct theorem was open mapping theorem, but now I know how to proceed. Clever idea by the way, but not obvious at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is Yes : the operator $A$ has to be compact. Here is a proof.

For every $n\in\mathbb N$, denote by $M_n$ the closure in $Y$ of the set $K(B(0,n))$, where $B(0,n)$ is the ball with radius $n$ centred at $0$. Then each $M_n$ is compact because $K$ is a compact operator, and obviously $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}M_n$ contains $K(X)$. So we have $A(X)\subseteq \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} M_n$.

Now, define $C_n:=\{ x\in X;\; A(x)\in M_n\}$. The $C_n$ are closed subsets of $X$ because the $M_n$ are closed and $A$ is continuous, and $X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} C_n$. By the Baire category theorem, it follows that one can find $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $C_{n_0}$ has nonempty interior. So there is a nontrivial ball $B(x_0,r)$ contained in $C_{n_0}$, *i.e.* $A(B(x_0,r))\subseteq M_{n_0}$.

From this, one gets by the linearity of $A$ that $A(B(0,r))$ is contained in the translate $M_{n_0}-A(x_0)$, and hence that $A(B(0,1))\subseteq E:=\frac1r\bigl( M_{n_0}-A(x_0)\bigr)$. The set $E$ is compact because $M_{n_0}$ is, and this proves that $A$ is a compact operator.

Comment: As I commented above, the closed graph theorem gives a shorter argument.

Comment: I think both answers are great. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Jochen I didn't see your comment!

Comment: @newcworld001 You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** I would ask if it we're possible for such a compact $K$ to be surjective? Because then you can see immediately it wouldn't be true, *however*, $K$ cannot be surjective... (why?... [hint here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74063/compact-operators-surjection)) Beyond this, you should note that compact operators may be expressed as operator norm-limits of finite-rank operators, and given that the range of $A$ sits inside the range of $K$, then $A$ should also be a norm-limit of finite rank operators.

Comment: It is not true in general that compact operators are operator norm limits of finite rank operators. It is true, however, in Hilbert spaces.