# Compact onto linear operator from Banach space imply space is finite-dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

I am trying to prove this question, which from the book Foundations of Modern Analysis by Avner Friedman pp189 5.1.7. the question is below.

Let **T** be a compact linear operator from a Banach space **X** onto itself. If $\mathbf{T^{-1}}$ is a bounded operator, then **X** is finite-dimensional.

I think this question is not right, because if **T** is a compact operator then **T** is a bounded operator and due to the open-mapping theorem,  $\mathbf{T^{-1}}$ must be bounded. It seems that this question just tells us that T is one-one and onto.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74063/compact-operators-on-an-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-cannot-be-surjective?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two key facts here.

$(1)$ The compact operators form an ideal.

$(2)$ The identity operator on a space $X$ is compact if and only if $X$ has finite-dimension.

By your assumption, $T \circ T^{-1}= 1_X$ and $T$ is compact. Because of $(1)$, we see that $1_X$ is compact. By $(2)$, $X$ has finite-dimension.

Comment: Thank you so much!